# How does cb_adf algorithm know a new action is available in the data if no feature is associated with arms?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

From the documentations I have read, cb_adf format multiline data is suitable for scenarios where number of actions are changing over time. My questions is, how does the algorithm know if a new action is available? Is code like formatting the logged bandits data correct?

```
two_actions = """
shared | a:0.5 b:1 c:2
0:-0.1:0.75 |
|
"""
```

and

```
three_actions_now = """
shared | a:0.5 b:1 c:2
|
0:-0.3:0.55 |
|
"""
```

And what about if one action is no longer available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use some identity feature for the arms which have no other features, this is because for cb_adf the actions themselves are essentially defined as the set of their features.

```
shared | a:0.5 b:1 c:2
| action_1
0:-0.3:0.55 | action_2
| action_3
```

If the action is no longer available you would omit the line that corresponded to that feature. So, if we wished to remove action_2 from the pool of actions to be chosen from it might look like.

```
shared | a:0.5 b:1 c:2
| action_1
| action_3
```

cb_adf works best when there is more than just a single feature per action. For example, having features shared across actions allows the learner to learn the value of other features from rewards on other actions.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Just wanted to confirm, would it make sense as well if we interact the action feature and the shared features? so in your case the features could be action_1*a, action_1*b, action_1*c etc.

Comment: Certainly, in fact often times to actually learn an effective model those interactions required. That's where personalization actually occurs, by learning the relationship between shared features an actions (or action features)